# Uniform values for storing constant values in a shaders OpenGL ES 2.0/3.0

Tags: java, opengl-es, shader

The Android application uses uniform to transfer the color vector to shaders. Transfer to the shader is done once:

```
private final int colorLink;
private final float[] color;

public Object3D(float[] color) {
    this.color = color;
    colorLink = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "u_color");
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) { 
    if(objectJustCreated) { // check will be performed anyway
        objectJustCreated = false;
        GLES20.glUniform4f(colorLink, color[0], color[1], 
            color[2], color[3]); 
        ...
    }
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es
uniform vec4 u_color;
out vec4 fragColor;
...
void main()
{
    ...
    fragColor = u_color * texColor;
}
```

Another option is to use a constant:

```
out vec4 fragColor;
const vec4 c_color = vec4(1.0, 0.7, 0.1, 1.0);
...
void main()
{
    ...
    fragColor = c_color * texColor;
}
```

But then will need to create several different shaders with different colors.

Which option is better to use in terms of performance or not a big difference? Would be grateful for any answer/comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found in the literature. Any parameter in the shader that remains unchanged for all vertices or fragments must be passed as a uniform-variable. Variables whose value is known at compile time should be constants, not uniform-variables, for performance reasons.